# Google oauth redirect with query string

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Google's oauth2.0 system in order to access calendar apis.

Is there a way to add query strings to Google's oauth2.0 authentication? So far, if I want to redirect with a query string, I have to do the following

- www.example.com/?query_string=1
- www.example.com/?query_string=2
- www.example.com/?query_string=3
- www.example.com/?query_string=4
- snip
- www.example.com/?query_string=9999999999

Which is neither feasible nor the sign of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `state` in the query string in the access request, the value will be replicated in the redirected url.

For example:

Access request uri (when user click *login with google*)

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
redirect_uri=http://your_uri.com/callback&
state=<state>&
...
```

Redirected uri (after user consent)

```
http://your_uri.com/callback#
state=<state>
...
```